# Parametrise uses parameter in GitHub Actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

How I can pass  parameter `inputs.custom` to this actions code:

```yaml
jobs:
  test-custom:
    name: Test Custom
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work4-${{ inputs.custom }}.yml
```

**Fully working example:**

First workflow `work1-build.yml`:

```yaml
name: Start workflow fail

on: [push]

jobs:  
  build-fail:
    name: Build with other workflow
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work3-build-fail.yml
    with:
      custom: custom-name1
```

Second workflow `work3-build-fail.yml`:

```
name: Build fail with input test

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      custom:
        description: Some custom string
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  test-custom:
    name: Test Custom
    uses: ./.github/workflows/work4-${{ inputs.custom }}.yml
```

Third workflow `work4-custom-name1.yml`

```yaml
name: Custom 1

on:
  workflow_call
  
jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "IN CUSTOM 1"
```

Example above make GitHub respond with an error:

```
Invalid workflow file
error parsing called workflow
".github/workflows/work1-build.yml"
-> "./.github/workflows/work3-build-fail.yml" (source branch with sha:720087c8794e76f52277f9b1229b44ea65ab89d5)
--> "./.github/workflows/work4-${{ inputs.custom }}.yml"
: failed to fetch workflow: workflow was not found.
```

I can successfully add `${{ inputs.custom }}` to:

```
  test-print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Print input
    steps:       
      - name: Step print input
        run: echo ${{ inputs.custom }}
```

Docs doesn't contain any examples with `uses` parametrisation:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses

Comment: From `uses: ./.github/actions/run-${{ inputs.custom }}`, looks like you're reusing a workflow residing in the same repo. According to [Calling a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow), "**You call a reusable workflow by using the `uses` keyword. Unlike when you are using actions within a workflow, you call reusable workflows directly within a job, and not from within job steps.**". So, you need to fix the syntax for calling that reusable workflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I corrected example, since I just pasted example form GitHub docs. Anyway on job level this isn't working too :D

Comment: Please update your workflow for `inputs` as well. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you cannot use inputs on `uses:`, if you look at your jobs all of the reusable actions/workflows are source before running anything. Is your error different now that you are referencing actions instead of workflows?

Comment: @aknosis question was updated with fully working example so hope there is no field for doubts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found documentation that proves this isn't possible. There is no supporting info stating that the `uses` key has access to any contexts.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability

I believe this is an architectural limitation of GitHub Actions, it appears they want to resolve all workflows/actions at the start of all jobs and thus dynamic resolution isn't possible.